# How to use "gets" and "gets.chomp" in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I learned that `gets` creates a new line and asks the user to input something, and `gets.chomp` does the same thing except that it does not create a new line. `gets` must return an object, so you can call a method on it, right? If so, lets name that object returned by `gets` as `tmp`, then you can call the `chomp` method of `tmp`. But before `gets` returns `tmp`, it should print a new line on the screen. So what does `chomp` do? Does it remove the new line **after the `gets` created it?**

Another way to re-expound my question is: Are the following actions performed when I call `gets.chomp`?

1. `gets` prints a new line
2. `gets` returns `tmp`
3. `tmp.chomp` removes the new line
4. User input

Is this the right order?

Comment: `gets` does not create a new line. The user inputs it. `gets` only passes that.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

`gets` lets the user input a line and returns it as a value to your program. This value includes the trailing line break. If you then call `chomp` on that value, this line break is cut off. So no, what you have there is incorrect, it should rather be:

1. `gets` *gets* a line of text, *including* a line break at the end.

   - This *is* the user input
2. `gets` returns that line of text as a string value.
3. Calling `chomp` on that value removes the line break

The fact that you see the line of text on the screen is only because you entered it there in the first place. `gets` does not magically suppress output of things you entered.

Answer (score 21):

The question shouldn't be "Is this the right order?" but more "is this is the right way of approaching this?"

Consider this, which is more or less what you want to achieve:

1. You assign a variable called `tmp` the return value of `gets`, which is a String.
2. Then you call String's [`chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) method on that object and you can see that `chomp` removed the trailing new-line.

   Actually what `chomp` does, is remove the <kbd>Enter</kbd> character ("`\n`") at the end of your string. When you type <kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd>, one character at a time, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> `gets` takes all the letters *and* the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key's new-line character ("`\n`").

   ```
   1. tmp = gets
   hello
   =>"hello\n"

   2. tmp.chomp
   "hello"
   ```

`gets` *is* your user's input. Also, it's good to know that *`gets` means "get string" and `puts` means "put string". That means these methods are dealing with Strings only.

Answer (score 3):

**chomp** is the method to remove trailing new line character i.e. '\n' from the the string.
whenever "gets" is use to take i/p from user it appends new line character i.e.'\n' in the end of the string.So to remove '\n' from the string '**chomp**' is used.

str = **"Hello ruby\n"**

str = str.chomp

puts str

**o/p**

**"Hello ruby"**

Comment: To clarify: `chomp` removes _a single trailing new-line character_. If multiple trailing new-lines exist you have to either loop until they're all gone, or you have to strip them another way. The new-line character is not added by `gets`, it's the Enter character the keyboard driver returns after pressing that key. `gets` only returns what it was given and returns control to the code once it sees "`\n`".

Answer (score 3):

`chomp` returns a new String with the given record separator removed from the end of `str` (if present).

See the [Ruby String API](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html)  for more information.

Answer (score 1):

- "gets" allows user input but a new line will be added after the string (string means text or a sequence of characters)

  "gets.chomp" allows user input as well just like "gets", but there is
  not going to be a new line that is added after the string.

Proof that there are differences between them:

Gets.chomp

```
puts "Enter first text:"
text1 = gets.chomp
puts "Enter second text:"
text2 = gets.chomp
puts text1 + text2
```

Gets:

```
puts "Enter first text:"
text1 = gets
puts "Enter second text:"
text2 = gets
puts text1 + text2
```

Copy paste the code I gave you, run and you will see and know that they are both different.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
x = gets
y = gets
puts x+y
```

and

```
x = gets.chomp
y = gets.chomp
puts x+y
```

Now run the two examples separately and see the difference.

Comment: What you are trying to point out, the user already knows. The question is about clarification of matter.

Comment: For anyone wondering what this does, run the examples in IRB or Pry and it will be more obvious.