# Ask for input and get an output

Tags: ruby

I am trying to ask a question and give back something depending on the answer. Here is my code:

```
X = 1
Y = 2
puts "x = 1 and y = 2"
puts "what is  x + y?"
user_input = gets.chomp
if user_input == 3
  print "Correct"
elsif user_input != 3
  print "Wrong"
end
```

It asks what 1+2 is, and if you input 3, it prints wrong, but if you input something else, it still replies back with wrong.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @KayZ or someone with editing privileges, could you format the code correctly so it's easier to see where the line breaks are?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that [`gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/Tutorial/part_02/user_input.html) will give you back user input as a string. When the user types 3, user_input becomes the string "3" and you are then comparing this to the integer 3.  The two are not the same.

To fix, you'll need to convert the user input to an integer with [`to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-to_i):

```
X = 1
Y = 2
puts "x = 1 and y = 2"
puts "what is x + y?"
user_input = gets.to_i

if user_input == 3
    print "Correct"
else
    print "Wrong"
end
```

Comment: `gets` (short for "get string") returns the string value of the user's input. [More info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193813/how-does-gets-and-gets-chomp-in-ruby-work)

Comment: A small point: `gets.to_i` is sufficient. You don't need to remove `\n` unless you're chomping at the bit to get rid of it.

Comment: Thank you, now it works fine, but could you explain what is the difference between user_input = gets.chomp and user_input = gets.to_i.  Please.