# Number multiplication in Ruby returning string concatenation instead of integer product

Tags: ruby

The following code to double a number is not working as expected.
E.g., if input is 5, it is returning 55 instead of 10.

```
# program to double a number taken from user input using user defined method    
def double (x)
  puts("Lets yield!")
  yield x * 2
end

puts "Enter number you want to double : "
x = gets.chomp

double (x) { |n| puts n }
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you are using the `*` method on a string. Convert `x` to an integer.

```
x = gets.chomp.to_i
```

Comment: i am not putting 5 as a string...     I am giving input as a number .

Comment: When you use `gets.chomp` you always have a string

Comment: add `puts x.class` after that line

Comment: @user8567677 why would you need `chomp` then? A number cannot contain a newline, can it?

Comment: @user8567677 A string can contain only digits, and still be a string! `123` is an `Integer`; `"456"` is a `String`. [`gets` will always interpret the input as a `String`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-gets).

Comment: ...And if you look at [the ruby docs for `String`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-2A), you'll see that `String * Integer` returns a repeated `String`.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193813/how-does-gets-and-gets-chomp-in-ruby-work), We take input using `gets` but it causes a problem of taking `\n` as a part of the input at the end of the string for example:

```
x=gets #Enter amr as input then it will print 4, three chars + \n
print x.length
```

here came `gets.chomp` which gets rid of `\n` in the end, So both `gets` and `gets.chomp` take the input as a string so you need to convert it as @Ursus mentioned before by using `gets.chomp.to_i`