# Print loop results on the same line instead of a new line for each iteration

Tags: ruby

I want my code to print `silly` only on one line but instead it prints it like this:

```
silly
silly
silly
```

I want this:

```
silly silly silly
```

This is my code:

```
    def print_silly_name ()
       i = 0
       while ( i < 60 )
         puts "silly"
         i += 1 
       end
    end

    def main
      name = read_string('Please enter your name: ')
      if ( name == "benyamin") or ( name == "jack" )
        puts  " #{name} that is a nice name"
      else 
        puts print_silly_name
      end
    end

    main
```

Comment: You want to use `print`, not `puts`

Comment: You should use `||` instead of `or`. The latter is a control flow operator and probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't really clear but I guess you wan't something like that :

```
def print_silly_name
  puts Array.new(60, 'silly').join(' ')
end

def main
  name = read_string('Please enter your name: ')
  if ( name == "benyamin") || ( name == "jack" )
    puts  " #{name} that is a nice name"
  else 
    print_silly_name
  end
end

main
```

Comment: This doesn't even print anything. You're just making a string

Comment: I know ^^
I adapted to its use of the function : `puts print_silly_name`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you have a few issues there:

1. The main one you mentioned in your question and title is that the name you print comes in a new row for each iteration of the loop. That's because you're using `puts` but should be using `print` in your case. [You can read more about that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018633/what-is-the-difference-between-print-and-puts)

2.You're calling the `#read_string` method which isn't defined anywhere in your code. What you want to do is either replace it with `gets.chomp` [More about gets here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193813/how-does-gets-and-gets-chomp-in-ruby-work) or define your `#read_string` method like this:

```
def read_string
  gets.chomp
end
```

3.As Stefan mentioned, you're using `or` which probably isn't what you're looking for here ([More about that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083112/difference-between-or-and-in-ruby)) You're better off using the `||` operator in your case.

Fixing these mistakes brings us to a working version of your code:

```
def print_silly_name_60_times
  60.times do
    print "silly "
  end
end

def main
  name = gets.chomp
  if ( name == "benyamin") || ( name == "jack" )
    puts  " #{name} that is a nice name."
  else
    print_silly_name_60_times
  end
end

main
```

After cleaning up a few things and making it a bit more compact, we get:

```
def print_silly_name_60_times
  60.times{print "silly "}
end

def main
  name = gets.chomp
  %w(benyamin jack).include?(name) ? (puts  " #{name} that is a nice name.") : print_silly_name_60_times
end

main
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this to print silly 60 times

`def print_silly_name ()
    puts "silly "* 60
 end`